# Set a Variable with a async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node project, I want to populate a var with the return value of a function that make async stuff :

index.js

```
const search = require( './search.js' );

(async () => {
    try {
        var test =  await search.searchMU('test');
        console.log(test);
    } catch (e) {

    }
})();
```

Search.js

```
const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );
exports.searchMU = function( searchInput ) {
    const fullUrl = url + excludes + type + display + search + searchInput;
    puppeteer.launch().then( async browser => {
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto( fullUrl );
      var html = await page.content();
      await browser.close();
      return html;
    } );
}
```

Output :

> undefined

Comment: `searchMU` doesn't return anything, add a `return` statement before `puppeteer.launch....`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789093/await-for-asynchronous-function-results-in-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `await search.searchMU()` but `searchMU` does not return a promise. Also, why use explicit promise chaining style (`.then(...)`) if you can use `await` everywhere?

```
exports.searchMU = async function( searchInput ) {
    const fullUrl = url + excludes + type + display + search + searchInput;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto( fullUrl );
    var html = await page.content();
    await browser.close();
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I did like the doc : https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-class-puppeteer